# Get Cookie in Java

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies

I want to get the cookie value sent from a web browser from a Java application.

The cookie is not sent in response headers from the WebServer. I think the cookie is being sent as a Session cookie - which I am not able to get the cookie value in Java application.

I tried this:

```
             CookieHandler handler = CookieHandler.getDefault();
             if (handler != null)    {
                  Map<String, List<String>> headers = handler.get(url.toURI(), new HashMap<String, List<String>>());
                  List<String> values = headers.get("Cookie");
                  for (Iterator<String> iter=values.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                       String v = iter.next(); 

                       if (cookieValue == null) 
                            cookieValue = v; 
                       else
                            cookieValue = cookieValue + ";" + v; 
                  } 
             }
```

but my efforts in vain, I am not able to get the cookie. I tried simply typing the URL in the browser, and I am able to see the 'Cookie' in the browser, but I am not able to get the same cookie from the java program - any help could be greatly helpful

---

Thanks BalusC, I will explain the issue.

I was actually looking out for a Cookie from Google Analytics and the Cookie is of the form "__gads:ID=blah".

This Cookie is sent to the Client only for the first time and if it already exists - Google Analytics wont send the Cookie again (all these days I am Checking for this Cookie)

Now my question where can I find this Cookie, which should be already existing in my system. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This won't work. The [`java.net.CookieHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html) is completely unrelated to the webbrowser-specific cookie stores. The `CookieHandler` is only been used when [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) is been used to programmatically fire HTTP requests using Java language (see also [this mini tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests))

If you intend to access a webbrowser-specific cookie store, then you'd have to use their Java API -if any provided by the particular webbrowser make-, or to look/guess their location at the disk file system and/or in the platform-specific registry, depending on the webbrowser make/version and the platform used.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but I am sorry I think I haven't asked the question correctly. I did a http request to the server (via URL.openConnection()) and used the above code to get the cookies, but I could always see that no cookies are returned. But when I requested the same server from the web browser I could see the cookies (I saw this from the Developer tools in Chrome). I dont know what mistake I did. :(

Comment: Click the "mini tutorial" link.